# Why do I get two redirectResponses when receiving one 302 response?

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, httpresponse, http-status-code-302

I use the following code:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"Received redirect Response: %@ %@", [response allHeaderFields], [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[response statusCode]]);
return request;
}
```

When I receive a 302 with the following header data:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found  
< Date: Wed, 03 Mar 2010 07:47:17 GMT  
< Server: lighttpd/1.4.19  
< Content-length: 0  
< Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8  
< Location: `<new Location>`  
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

this is the output in gdb console:

> 2010-03-03 08:42:03.265 MyProg[68106:207] Received redirect Response:
>   (null) server error   2010-03-03 08:42:14.414 MyProg[68106:207]
>   Received redirect Response: {
>       Connection = "Keep-Alive";
>       "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
>       "Content-Length" = 20;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Wed, 03 Mar 2010 07:42:10 GMT";
>       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=100";
>       Location = "`<new Location>`";
>       Server = "lighttpd/1.4.19";
>       Vary = "Accept-Encoding";   } found

When using Curl I only get one response and tracedump tells the same, so I am sure that the server sends only one redirect.
Why is this selector called twice?

Comment: I found that when checking the request the in the first call you receive the original request and in the second call an empty HTTPBody with the following HTTPHeader:  
(gdb) po [request allHTTPHeaderFields]  
{  
    Accept = "*/*";  
    "Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate";  
    "Accept-Language" = "en-us";  
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` gets called before every request, so it is called once on the original request, which was not a redirect so response is nil; then it gets called when loading the redirection target, where response is the 302 response to the initial request.